# How does one require macros when the CLJS node.js repl fires up?

Tags: node.js, clojurescript, core.async

Here is a sample clojurescript `repl.clj` config file:

```
(require '[cljs.repl])
(require '[cljs.repl.node])

(cljs.repl/repl 
  (cljs.repl.node/repl-env)
  :watch "src"
  :output-dir "out-repl"
  :repl-requires '[[cljs.nodejs :as node]
                   [cljs.core.async :refer [put! chan <! >!]]])
```

Notice the part that `:repl-requires` some useful `cljs.core.async` functions.

​**Question:**​ How does one `:repl-require` core.async ​**macros**​? In particular, how would one `:repl-requires` the `go` macro from `cljs.core.async.macros` (i.e., so that when one loads up a nodejs repl, the `go` macro is immediately usable)?

Comment: Did you try using form `'[cljs.core.async :refer [put! chan <! >!] :refer-macros [go]]`? (https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure#namespaces)

Comment: Yes -- it yields an error.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? I was able to use the syntax from my first comment for symbols from `cljs.pprint` (e.g. `:repl-requires '[[cljs.pprint :refer [pprint] :refer-macros [pp]]]`) so the error might be cause by some other issue. Even `cljs.repl/repl*` uses the same syntax for default value of `repl-requires`. (https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/177b05fc5935c659e4829b7b1798e216b6797bec/src/main/clojure/cljs/repl.cljc#L778)